# Can you find $Mat(id, F, \epsilon)$ given only $Mat(L, F, F)$ and $Mat(L, \epsilon, \epsilon)$?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Let $\epsilon, F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bases.

Can you find matrix $Mat(id, F, \epsilon)$ given only $Mat(L, F, F)$ and $Mat(L, \epsilon, \epsilon)$?

---

$Mat(id,F,E)$ is change of basis matrix from basis $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

$Mat(L,E,E)$ is a matrix of linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ from basis $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Using a known theorem one can write:

$Mat(L,\epsilon,\epsilon)=B=D^{-1}AC$
$=Mat(id, F,\epsilon)Mat(L,F,F)Mat(id,\epsilon, F)$

Answer (score 0):

No, in general you have no chance. Let $L$ be the identity. The matrix with respect to $F$ or $\epsilon$ will always be the unit matrix, but the matrix with respect to both bases can be any invertible matrix.

Comment: I've modified the question a bit, I had it wrongly formulated at first.

Comment: Does not change anything. If $L= id$, then $Mat(L,F,F)$ will not carry any information on $F$.